# Unauthenticated users cannot access static files in ASP.NET MVC regardless of location elements

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, web-config, telerik, authorization

I know this question has been asked several times on SO, but none of those answers have worked in my situation. I have an ASP.NET MVC2 app that uses Forms authentication on my local IIS 7.5(7600.16385) on an AppPool running in integrated mode. Interestingly, this **does not happen** when using the development web server that comes with VS 2010. My web.config file contains no `<authorization />` and no `<location />` elements. When I hit the home page, I get everything in the logon view except for the .CSS and .PNG files stored in the `~/Content` directory. When I directly request the .CSS file with http://localhost/WebSubscribers/Content/Site.css, I am redirected to the logon page. It seems like a wild-card mapping tries to authorize every request even when I allow that request using `<location path="Content" />` as shown below:

```
<location path="Content" >
 <system.web>
  <authorization>
   <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
 </system.web>
</location>
```

Most of the answers I found on Stack Overflow suggest adding just such a location element to fix the problem, but that does not work for me so I removed it.

I created no wild-card mappings in IIS and, just to make sure, I removed the site and re-created it pointing at the same directory, only to get the same results. Can a wild-card mapping be specified anywhere other than IIS? Can my web.config file have "acquired" some kind of wild-card mapping? I use the Telerik MVC controls, which appear to have made some changes (registered namespaces, httpHandlers, modules) to the web.config file.

Any other suggestions?

**UPDATE:** When using Chrome to hit the website without being authenticated, the "Resources" developer tool says the following about my Site.css file: "Site.css:-1Resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html."

Where would such a mime type be set? The site's node in IIS says ".css | text/css | Inherited".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found both the cause and solution to my problem in IIS. The web app runs in IIS from within my Visual Studio Projects directory, so I configured it to use an AppPool that runs under my user account. In IIS, the **Anonymous Authentication** feature was configured as **Specific user: IUSR**. I do not know why or how. When I changed this back to **Application pool identity**, unauthenticated users could access static files.

+1 to [Craig Stuntz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7714/craig-stuntz) for pointing out that wild-card mappings as well as the location elements are not needed for MVC and IIS 7.

Comment: This saved me loads of time - would like to be able to vote it up twice :) Thanks

Comment: If I could give you more than one +1 I would. I've been ripping my hair out with this one. I was also trying adding to my web.config the <location path=.... that you mentioned, and it just wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using a wild card mapping for IIS 7 in integrated mode. You only need that for IIS 6 / "classic" mode. You don't need the location element, either; this "just works."

Comment: I didn't create any new mappings. In fact, I just removed the web app from IIS, created a new one pointing at the same directory, requested http://localhost/websubscribers/content/site.css, and got the log on page again.